# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: access_denied

Tags: java, linux, ssl, https, sslhandshakeexception

I have the below program (downloaded from net and edited) which gives me a error "**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: access_denied**" when I run. Across SO and else where I see many solutions for "handshake_failure" none for "access_denied". The OS is RHEL 7.4

My original issue is not when connecting to google.com but while connecting to 3rd party service.  The program having this code runs from behind a proxy. I have specified the proxy server and port as parameter when I run the program. I get the above error irrespective of the end point URL. So it seems to be some settings on the local machine. Any suggestions on what  could be wrong with the setting?? The articles I read mention that a CLientHello goes out from the client and the server responds with a ServerHello. I have tried running the program with **-Djavax.net.debug=all** and see ClientHello goes out but does not receive a ServerHello back.

Java version details

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

I have tried using both the limited and unlimited jars from jre/lib/security directory of $JAVA_HOME. Though probably not necessary I have explicitly tried specifying the location to my cacerts file as a truststore.

The code is below

```
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class TestHttps {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
      HttpHost target = new HttpHost("www.google.com", 443, "https");

      HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("/");
      System.out.println("executing request to " + target);

      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(target, getRequest);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```